# Particle slides on incline where incline angle increases with rate $\omega$: why does kinetic energy have a term $(1/2)m(\omega^2 x^2)$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, rotational-dynamics

> A particle slides on a smooth inclined plane whose inclination is $\theta$ is increasing at a constant rate $w$. If $\theta = 0$, at time t = 0 at which time the particle start from rest, Find the subsequent motion of the particle.

This problem can be solved with Lagrangian methods.
The kinetic and potential energies are

$$T = \frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2 + \frac{1}{2}m(\omega^2x^2)$$
$$V = mgh = m g x \sin(wt) \, .$$

Where does the $\frac{1}{2}m(\omega^2x^2)$ come from?

Comment: Question titles should help people choose which questions to read and answer, and help searching. The original title "Mechanics question" was much to vague to have any real value so I edited it. This is a website for questions and answers about physics. Every post is a question, so there's no need to remind the reader that the question is a question by saying so in the title. Also, just saying "mechanics" isn't particularly helpful. Check [this meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles) for information on writing good titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to think of this problem using a polar coordinate system. $x$ is essentially the radius $r$ or $\rho$, measured from pivotal. $w$ is simply the angular velocity. So the position vector of the object is

$x\hat{\vec r}+\theta\hat{\vec \theta}$

So the velocity vector is

$\dot x\hat{\vec r}+w\hat{\vec \theta}$

The hatted vectors are unit.

So the second term of $T$ is "the rotational kinetic energy".

Comment: I don't understand how is x r ? can you explain more please ?

Comment: I guess $x$ is $r$ from the expressions of $T$ and $V$. Especially, $V$ implies that $h=x\sin wt$. You probably want to check notes to say if your professor actually defined $x$ to be $r$.